# Avoid parsedatetime in H2?

Tags: h2

Is there a way for setting a default date-parser for h2? Background is that I want to use the same script that we use to init our Oracle-DB for H2, and I want to avoid having to convert too much in the script.

H2 does not automatically parse "dd.MM.yyyy" Strings, but it works fine with the parsedatetime. Is there a way to set a "global" Dateparser or Dateformat that will be used by default?

Comment: Using standard ANSI DATE literals should work with Oracle and H2, e.g.: `DATE '2019-22-10'`  (btw: Oracle does not automatically parse dates in the format `dd.MM.yyyy` either - that completely depends on the configuration of the client running the script)

Comment: Thanks, you are right (kind of)... ;) If I check the standard format for Oracle, I get "DD.MM.RR" (`SELECT value FROM   nls_session_parameters WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';`. Is there a way of setting this on H2?

Comment: If this page is actual, it does not seem to be possible. :( 
http://www.h2database.com/html/roadmap.html

Comment: Don't read the roadmap, read the manual: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#date

Comment: The manual only states the default format that is accepted. However, since our Oracle guys changed the NLS_DATE_FORMAT, I don't want any strange hacks... ;) I was able to fix the issue using the to_date function, this works fine in both DBs, and it is "ok" to have the script this way, even in Oracle, so it will not be vulnerable to NLS_DATE_FORMAT changes. ;)

Comment: The manual clearly states that the ANSI SQL literal `DATE '2019-22-10'` is supported.

Comment: Yep, however my question was wether I can override it like in Oracle, because our Oracle DB has a different NLS_DATE_FORMAT and I did not want to use different sql scripts on each db... However, I managed to solve it using the to_date, so I can use the same format (no matter if ansi or anything else) without having to know any configuration specifics of the db...